# site identity will not update

Tags: wp-admin

my host is bluehost.
i use wordpress to work on site currently.
i am using trends theme.
my site is www.sylverwolfenterprise.com

i spelled a word wrong and forgot to upload an image for my site identity. When I tried to correct it, it does not take.

I have tried turning off server side cache.
I have cleared cookies and cache on my side, I have run ccleaner, I have deleted everything, saved draft, then publish to no avail.

what am i missing?

Comment: Hi, and welcome! Your question is not eloquent enough for someone to help you. You might want to explain what does "site identity" identity mean to you? Is it your logo? Please, consider using global vocabulary here. Also, you could provide the community screenshots and more context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try loading the page with a query_string on the end, to make sure you're not still getting a page cached somewhere.  like https://www.sylverwolfenterprise.com?123

Comment: Thanks. That was the issue all along. appreciate it sorry i cant upvote you.